# overriding model in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to override

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Address/AbstractAddress.php
```

for remove lastname validation.How to override this?

di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" type="Xxx\Lastname\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" />
```

AbstractAddress.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Xxx\Lastname\Model\Address;


class AbstractAddress extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress
{
   public function validate()
    {
        $errors = [];
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'firstname']);
        }
//
//        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
//            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'lastname']);
//        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getStreetLine(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'street']);
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'city']);
        }

        if ($this->isTelephoneRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'telephone']);
            }
        }

        if ($this->isFaxRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getFax(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'fax']);
            }
        }

        if ($this->isCompanyRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getCompany(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'company']);
            }
        }

        $_havingOptionalZip = $this->_directoryData->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
        if (!in_array(
            $this->getCountryId(),
            $_havingOptionalZip
        ) && !\Zend_Validate::is(
            $this->getPostcode(),
            'NotEmpty'
        )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'postcode']);
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getCountryId(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'countryId']);
        }

        if ($this->getCountryModel()->getRegionCollection()->getSize() && !\Zend_Validate::is(
            $this->getRegionId(),
            'NotEmpty'
        ) && $this->_directoryData->isRegionRequired(
            $this->getCountryId()
        )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'regionId']);
        }

        if (empty($errors) || $this->getShouldIgnoreValidation()) {
            return true;
        }
        return $errors;
    }


}
```

Comment: could you show your full code?

Comment: Updated above code @Rakesh Jesadiya

Comment: Could you please replace classname xxx with Xxx.

Comment: Ok.But Still it's not working

Comment: Try with aroundPlugin instead of preference

Comment: remove var folder and check

Comment: Please specify aroundPlugin php file

Comment: removed var folder.no difference in there

Answer (score 4):

Create a plugin to override functionality of the method:
Step 1: `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress">
        <plugin name="aroundAddressValidation" type="Xxx\Lastname\Plugin\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create Plugin class `AbstractAddress.php`

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\Lastname\Plugin\Model\Address;

class AbstractAddress
{
    /**
    * Directory data
    *
    * @var \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data
    */
    protected $_directoryData = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
    ) {
        $this->_directoryData = $directoryData;
    }

    public function aroundValidate(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress $subject,
        callable $proceed) 
    {

        $errors = [];
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'firstname']);
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getStreetLine(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'street']);
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'city']);
        }

        if ($subject->isTelephoneRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'telephone']);
            }
        }

        if ($subject->isFaxRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFax(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'fax']);
            }
        }

        if ($subject->isCompanyRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCompany(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'company']);
            }
        }

        $_havingOptionalZip = $this->_directoryData->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
        if (!in_array(
            $subject->getCountryId(),
            $_havingOptionalZip
        ) && !\Zend_Validate::is(
            $subject->getPostcode(),
            'NotEmpty'
        )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'postcode']);
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCountryId(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'countryId']);
        }

        if ($subject->getCountryModel()->getRegionCollection()->getSize() && !\Zend_Validate::is(
            $subject->getRegionId(),
            'NotEmpty'
        ) && $subject->_directoryData->isRegionRequired(
            $subject->getCountryId()
        )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'regionId']);
        }

        if (empty($errors) || $subject->getShouldIgnoreValidation()) {
            return true;
        }
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Feel free to contact!

Comment: still it was loading page.....

Comment: remove cache and then try it.

Comment: page loading..........wt can i do

Comment: check console... or just die on function's 1st line to test.

Comment: just die on function's 1st line to test.after trying it.the condition die.flow correct.but ..

Comment: now die on last line of the function.

Comment: again loading....

Comment: _directoryData in above code?

Comment: Replace $this with $subject in whole function. Sorry I was just missed to replace it, Answer updated

Comment: Initialize  _directoryData into constructor, Answer Updated

Comment: Again loading..............

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69154/discussion-between-ronak-chauhan-and-mahalakshmi-m).

Comment: @RonakChauhan I tried this but getting following error "Invalid method Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor::isFaxRequired"  in line -> if ($subject->isFaxRequired()) {

Comment: @DavidCoder check if isFaxRequired() is available in parent class or not, if not then remove that.

Comment: @RonakChauhan, yes it is available in parent class.

Comment: @DavidCoder then please try after setup:upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: To edit/remove lastname validation (in 2.3.2), you need to replace argument that is passed in Magento\Customer\Model\Address\CompositeValidator in module-customer/etc/di.xml.

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\CompositeValidator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="validators" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="general" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Validator\General</item>
            <item name="country" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Validator\Country</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In your module etc/di.xml, add these lines:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\CompositeValidator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="validators" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="general" xsi:type="object">Company\YourModule\Model\Customer\Address\Validator\General</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

2. Step: Create class on the right path as mentioned in yourmodule/etc/di.xml.
   Company\YourModule\Model\Customer\Address\Validator\General

This is my class

```
<?php

namespace YourCompany\Module\Model\Customer\Address\Validator;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress;

class General
{
 /**
  * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
  */
 private $eavConfig;

 /**
  * @var \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data
  */
 private $directoryData;

 /**
  * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
  * @param \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData
  */
 public function __construct(
     \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
     \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData
 ) {
     $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
     $this->directoryData = $directoryData;
 }

 /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
 public function validate(AbstractAddress $address)
 {
     $errors = array_merge(
         $this->checkRequredFields($address),
         $this->checkOptionalFields($address)
     );

     return $errors;
 }

 /**
  * Check fields that are generally required.
  *
  * @param AbstractAddress $address
  * @return array
  * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
  */
 private function checkRequredFields(AbstractAddress $address)
 {
     $errors = [];
     if (!\Zend_Validate::is($address->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
         $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'firstname']);
     }

//        HERE is where the lastname is no longer required
//        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($address->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
//            $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'lastname']);
//        }

     if (!\Zend_Validate::is($address->getStreetLine(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
         $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'street']);
     }

     if (!\Zend_Validate::is($address->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
         $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'city']);
     }

     return $errors;
 }


 /**
  * Check fields that are conditionally required.
  *
  * @param AbstractAddress $address
  * @return array
  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
  * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
  */
 private function checkOptionalFields(AbstractAddress $address)
 {
     $errors = [];
     if ($this->isTelephoneRequired()
         && !\Zend_Validate::is($address->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')
     ) {
         $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'telephone']);
     }

     if ($this->isFaxRequired()
         && !\Zend_Validate::is($address->getFax(), 'NotEmpty')
     ) {
         $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'fax']);
     }

     if ($this->isCompanyRequired()
         && !\Zend_Validate::is($address->getCompany(), 'NotEmpty')
     ) {
         $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'company']);
     }

     $havingOptionalZip = $this->directoryData->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
     if (!in_array($address->getCountryId(), $havingOptionalZip)
         && !\Zend_Validate::is($address->getPostcode(), 'NotEmpty')
     ) {
         $errors[] = __('"%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.', ['fieldName' => 'postcode']);
     }

     return $errors;
 }

 /**
  * Check if company field required in configuration.
  *
  * @return bool
  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
  */
 private function isCompanyRequired()
 {
     return $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'company')->getIsRequired();
 }

 /**
  * Check if telephone field required in configuration.
  *
  * @return bool
  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
  */
 private function isTelephoneRequired()
 {
     return $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'telephone')->getIsRequired();
 }

 /**
  * Check if fax field required in configuration.
  *
  * @return bool
  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
  */
 private function isFaxRequired()
 {
     return $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'fax')->getIsRequired();
 }
}
```

**Remember not to extend Company\YourModule\Model\Customer\Address\Validator\General with Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Validator\General.**

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Tried your approach but it is not working(I'm working in Magento 2.3.2)

Comment: I've tried the preference way and added a constructor and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes. This is a good solution. It's working to me. I'm working Magento CE 2.3.4. I used this to remove city field validation under customer registration form. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in di.xml of your custom module or theme

```
<preference for="Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Address\File.php" type="Magento\Customer\Address\AbstractAddress"/>
```

You can use the code in di.xml in the above way

and in your class file

```
<?php

namepsace Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Address

class FileName extends Magento\Customer\Address\AbstractAddress
{
//your code goes here
}
?>
```

Comment: But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same situation where I needed to remove the "lastname" validation. Here how I solved this.

The actual issue lies in `Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Validator\General.php`, where "lastname" is hard coded as required. Since the method is `private` we can't use Plugin to intercept that method.

Refer: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

With Around Plugin, you can remove the validation in `AbstractAddress` Class.

Step 1: Alter Database schema of `customer_address_entity` table. Since `lastname` is not `nullable` by default.
File: app/code/Harish/Customer/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="customer_address_entity">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="lastname" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Last Name"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Step 1.1: Generate `db_schema_whitelist.json`

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Harish_Customer
```

Step 2: Make "Lastname" attribute's `is_required` property to `false` in `eav_attribute` table. I used a patch for this.
File: app/code/Harish/Customer/Setup/Patch/Data/RemoveLastnameRequiredFromAddressPatch.php

```
<?php

namespace Harish\Customer\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Address;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class RemoveLastnameRequiredFromAddressPatch implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * RemoveLastnameRequiredPatch constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param Address $address
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        Address $address
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
            $this->address->getEntityTypeId(),
            'lastname',
            [
                'is_required' => false
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Step 3: Create entry in di.xml for the Plugin.
File: app/code/Harish/Customer/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress">
        <plugin name="harish_customer_address_plugin" type="Harish\Customer\Plugin\Model\Address\AbstractAddressPlugin" />
</type>
```

Step 4: Create the Plugin Class and return true for the Lastname validation.
File: app/code/Harish/Customer/Plugin/Model/Address/AbstractAddressPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Harish\Customer\Plugin\Model\Address;

/**
 * Address abstract model
 */
class AbstractAddressPlugin
{
    /**
     * Validate address attribute values
     *
     * @return bool|array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function aroundValidate(\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $result = $proceed();

        $phrase = $result[0]->getArguments();
        if ( $phrase['fieldName'] == 'lastname') {
            return true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Step 6: Increment the module version (optional).
File: app/code/Harish/Customer/etc/module.xml

```
<module name="Harish_Customer" setup_version="1.2.0"/>
```

Step 5: Recompile for the system to pick the Plugin and also don't forget to run upgrade for applying the patch.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Done.
Note: I have used my custom module "Customer" under the vendor "Harish" to make this work, please update with yours.